# How to Query MongoDB Using Child Nodes in Java

Tags: java, mongodb, child-nodes

I'm trying to query mongodb with java. The name of my collection is: reads. Here is an example of a specific document I'm querying for:

```
{
"_id" : {
    "d" : "B66929932",
    "r" : "15500304",
    "eT" : ISODate("2014-09-29T12:03:00Z")
},
"v" : 169000,
"iT" : ISODate("2015-04-10T20:42:07.577Z")
```

}

I'm trying to query where r = 15500304, eT = 2014-09-29T12:03:00Z and v = 169000. I'm able to do this in mongo pretty easily:

```
db.reads.find({ "_id.r" : "15500304", "_id.eT" : ISODate("2014-09-29T12:03:00Z"), "$where" : "this.v == 169000;"}).pretty()
```

I'm unable to figure out how to structure this in java. So far I've got:

```
DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("reads");
BasicDBObject andQuery = new BasicDBObject();
List<BasicDBObject> obj = new ArrayList<BasicDBObject>();

obj.add(new BasicDBObject("_id.r", "15500304"));
obj.add(new BasicDBObject("_id.eT", "2014-09-29T12:03:00Z"));
obj.add(new BasicDBObject("v", 169000));
andQuery.put("$and", obj);

DBCursor cursor = collection.find(andQuery);
    while(cursor.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(cursor.next());
    }
```

My Question is: How do I query using these child nodes and return the matching document?

I'm unable to find any clear advice/examples online. Any and all advice is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close. Modify your query to:

```
DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("reads");
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
String dateInString = "2014-09-29T12:03:00Z";
Date date = df.parse(dateInString);

query.append("status.name", "Expired")
     .append("_id.eT", date)
     .append("v", 169000);
```

Or using **[QueryBuilder](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.6/com/mongodb/QueryBuilder.html)**:

```
DBObject query = QueryBuilder.start()
                         .put("_id.r").is("15500304")
                         .put("_id.eT").is(date)
                         .put("v").is(169000)
                         .get();

DBCursor cursor = collection.find(query);
while(cursor.hasNext()){
    System.out.println(cursor.next());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried both examples and I get an Illegal Argument Exception because it's unable to parse the Date. IntelliJ is also telling me that new Date(String str) is deprecated

Comment: @jdub7 I have updated my answer, can you let me know how that goes since I haven't tried it.

Comment: @chridam this is off-topic, but your answer yesterday was what I was looking for, as I am using spring driver where I cannot do concat, so your answer gave three distinct values, which I could concat in java. Thanks

Comment: @Rnet Thanks for the feedback, I will undelete the answer so that others with the same issue may find it useful. Cheers!

Comment: @chridam thanks again for the edit. It compiles and runs however it does not return anything. If I take out the date portion of the query, it runs fine and returns query results. However, the date is a crucial part of this query. It's like Mongo doesn't recognize that it's a date. I don't know if it helps but I'm running Mongo version 2.4.10 and Java 1.7.0_75

doesn't recognize that it's a date.

Comment: @chridam Turns out your code worked. The issue was that the timezone for the date my query was using was my machine's timezone which is EST. I had to hard code in UTC and it worked. I hate working with Dates! Thank you again for your help!

Comment: @jdub7 No worries :-) Glad that it worked out for you in the end.